# Points Solar Radiation reformat problem

Tags: python, arcpy

I am trying to produce a set of monthly solar radiation maps based on a monthly parameterization of the diffuse proportion and transmissivity (i.e. new values for both parameters each month). The PointsSolarRadiation function in arcpy produces a full year of monthly radiation values for each function call (i.e. 12 months all based on the same diffuse proportion and transmissivity values). I am trying to extract only the specific month from each of the twelve output files (i.e. extract the "April" data from the file run using the "April" parameters).

To do this I have a subsequent for loop which calls the individual files, identifies the appropriate data column in the file, extracts the data (using SearchCursor) then appends it to the placeholder. The *append* method fails on the second iteration, which does not happen if I run this with a simpler example of appending defined lists.

My code is as follows:

```
tableMonthHolder = []
for (j, value) in enumerate(diffuse):
    b = str(j)
    outFeatures = "c:/.../output" + b + ".shp"
    outTableFinder = "T"+b
    tableMonth = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(outFeatures,(outTableFinder))]
    tableMonthHolder = tableMonthHolder.append(tableMonth)
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redundantly redefining your variable `tableMonthHolder` in the last line of code. Try changing this line to:

```
tableMonthHolder.append(tableMonth)
```

Comment: Correct. And `list.append` returns `None`, so redefining `tableMonthHolder` is what blows it up as it lacks a `.append` method.